# Tableau connection cache issues with Mongo DB Atlas by MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, tableau-desktop

I am using the Mongo DB Atlas by MongoDB connector that is explained [here](https://www.mongodb.com/features/mongodb-tableau) to extract and use mongo db data in tableau, however there are some problems that I experience when new fields are added in my mongo documents. I have several new fields in one of the collections from the database that I am using in tableau and they are not shown in tableau even after data refresh. On the other hand older fields(columns) that have been deleted from mongo db are still shown in tableau but without any data. I have tried with downloading other version of tableau and the result is the same, no new columns and old ones are persisted. I have also tried deleting the cache, deleting tableau, creating new connections and removing older ones, still not working. Did anyone ever experienced that and have any idea what the problem may be.

I am on MacOS and I am using Tableau Desktop with the mongo db connector for tableau and jdbc connector jar. The data is extracted from a Atlas SQL federated instance as mentioned in the link I shared.

Comment: Two questions; 1. Can you see the new data in a workbook but not on a published site? 2. Are you using a live connection to your database or are you connecting to the database and then creating a tableau extract? You may need to just set up and extract refresh, or run it manually after your MongoDB data is updated.

Comment: I am not able to see the new data in the workbook and the site is not published. And also i am using live connection, and i have refreshed the data several times.

Comment: This  post here may give more clue, I am experiencing the exact same problem https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D58b0000BOrozHCQR/new-data-source-column-not-showing

Comment: You may need to reconfigure your connector to the updated schema, so rather than re-running the refresh, you would need to re-run the creation of the connector.

Comment: How can I achieve that, if you can share some more details?

Comment: I have tried creating a new connection but it resulted with the same structure.

Comment: Try creating an advanced setup of a [federated database](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/query/sql/getting-started/get-started-advanced/#std-label-sql-get-started-advanced) and in the link you sent of the tableau question, one of the answers said they just needed to update their schema.

Comment: Thank you. Creating a federated database with advanced config did solved my issue.

Comment: I am glad it worked, I summarized the answer and posted it below, feel free to accept it so others may find it more easily than through the comments, no worries if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reconfigure the connector with the updated schema.

See: [advanced setup: Create a Federated Database](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/query/sql/getting-started/get-started-advanced/#std-label-sql-get-started-advanced)